# Zend 1 standalone service for JWT

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to create a service (for jwt logic) that will be standalone, but I see that it is not so easy to refer to the service I have to use 'new' and unfortunately then I create a new instance... :/ but I want to work globally (using public methods) on one and store the token value.

**application/service/Jwt.php**

```
<?php

class Application_Service_Jwt
{
    private $token;

    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    public function setToken($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }
}
```

**application/configs/services.global.php**

```
<?php
return [
    "services" => array(
        'Jwt' => new Application_Service_Jwt()
    )
];
```

**application/Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initServiceManager()
{
    $conf = glob(__DIR__ . "/configs/services.global.php", GLOB_BRACE);

    $serviceManagerConfigurator = new \Laminas\ServiceManager\Config($conf["services"]);
    $serviceManager = new \Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceManager();
    $serviceManagerConfigurator->configureServiceManager($serviceManager);

    // Register it into zend registry is not mandatory
    \Zend_Registry::set("serviceManager", $serviceManager);

    return $serviceManager;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to implement service manager in a ZF1 app?

Comment: Maybe I'm a front-end developer and have no experience with zend 1. I need to create a global service that I can access from any controller while keeping one instance. I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to implement Laminas Service Manager in ZF1 application. This also work with ZF2 and ZF3 Service manager since they are the same.

In your composer add this dependency

```
"laminas/laminas-servicemanager": "^3.4"
```

In your Bootstrap.php add this _init function

```
protected function _initServiceManager()
{
    $files = glob(__DIR__ . "/configs/{config,services}.{global,".APPLICATION_ENV."}.php", GLOB_BRACE);

    $conf = [];
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $conf = array_replace_recursive($conf, include($file));
    }

    $serviceManagerConfigurator = new \Laminas\ServiceManager\Config($conf["services"]);
    $serviceManager = new \Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceManager();
    $serviceManagerConfigurator->configureServiceManager($serviceManager);

    // Register it into zend registry is not mandatory
    \Zend_Registry::set("serviceManager", $serviceManager);

    return $serviceManager;
}
```

Now, under application/configs you should create the services.global.php file, where you can add your services definition (read the doc for all the possibilities it offers, [ZF2 version is ok](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html) )

```
return [
"services" => [,
    "factories" => [
        "hello" => function() {
            return "OK";
        }
]
```

]

In the same folder, add config.{ENVIRONMENT}.php files, where you can define properties depending on your ENVIRONMENT ( they are also loaded depending on its value )

```
return [
"myApiConfig" => [
  "endpoint" => "...",
  "username" => "...",
  "password" => "...",
],
```

From your controller you can access your service manager instances using both getResource or Zend registry, you can add this in your overridden init

```
    $this->serviceManager = $this->getFrontController()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('serviceManager');
```

And get any defined service

```
$this->serviceManager->get('hello');
```

You can also separate your service classes that use proper php namespaces adding the autoload key in your composer ( change the namespace name and directory as you wish )

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNewLibs\\": "library/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understand why I need the environment configuration (username, password etc)? How do I inform ServiceMenager about my Jwt.php service?

Comment: If your JWT is a "service" ( a configured class instance served as a singleton ) you should create a new key in your services.global.php and add a function that returns it. Then, if you need this service in some component, you should inject it ( preferabily using dependency injection ).